# AngularJS: How to get element height

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to find the height of an element and add a class to it if his height is greater than 300px.
I know that this question has some answers but I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

My goal is to add an overflow scrollbar if `text` has `height > 300px`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/98hawvgw/1/)

This what I've done so far:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('overflow', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            var height = elem.height();
            if(height>100) {
                elem.addClass('overflow');
            }
            else {
                elem.removeClass('overflow');
            }
        }
    };
})

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div overflow class="text">
    <p>
      long text long text long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elem.height()` is not a function so you can use scrollHeight property.

Check below fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshprajapati/U3pVM/24274/

Answer (score 0):

If in case you don't want to use angular or jquery and just want to use CSS then this solution should work -

```
.text p {
  max-width:300px;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98hawvgw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

add max-height: 300px; and overflow-y:scroll; property to CSS and use below code in the if condition.

`elem.addClass('text');`